# Help with power series $f(x)=\frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Given that $f(x)=\frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)$, find a power series for $f(x)$.  What is its radius of convergence?

So far I got the following:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(x^2\right)^n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2nx^{n-1}$$

And for the radius of convergence I did this:

$$\left|x^2\right|\lt1$$
$$\left|x\right|^2\lt1$$

So $R=1$

Please tell me if I went about solving this correctly, or provide hints as to how I can fix it.

Comment: I'd recommend writing full equations rather than isolated mathematical expressions. Makes it easier for people to know what you mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ill make some edits, please let me know if my edits address your suggestions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson well I just realized I don't know how to make the modifications you suggested.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: I mean, instead of just writing $$\sum(x^2)^n$$ write something like, Let $$g(x)=\sum(x^2)^n$$ Mathematics should read as complete English sentences, with verbs and connectives and such.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you very much, I will pay more attention to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work, though unlabelled, is mostly correct (assuming that I read between the lines well), except that you took the derivative of $x^{2n}$ incorrectly. Were this on a test (perhaps you are studying for finals season), I would expect much more explanation and fewer isolated math expressions.

Aesthetically, some might question the $n=0$ term and would instead rewrite the sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing what the derivative will be.  But would it instead be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2nx^{2n-1}$?

Comment: @inquisitor: Perhaps you are only having a hard time because of the big Sigma. But you are correct in this update. Remember, the derivative of $x^k$ is $kx^{k-1}$. So $x^{2n}$ has derivative $2nx^{2n - 1}$. You somehow lost the $2$ before.

Comment: I forgot to ask you, what's wrong with the $n=0$ term?  Why should I write it as $n=1$?  I've seen this done but don't completely understand why it has been done.

Comment: @inquisitor: naively, if you write out the series termwise you start with $1 + x^2 + x^4 + \ldots$. When you differentiate, the $1$ goes away, and so you are literally getting rid of the first term. In your sum, this happens to be represented because when $n=0$, your first term looks like $0\cdot \frac{1}{x}$, which happens to be $0$. But it's an ugly $0$.

Comment: I see!  Perfect explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should know that,

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}$$

for $|x|<1$.Try to use this to find the power series of $f$. Note that a power series could be differentiated term by term.

Comment: Adding a little more to my answer, I guess the way the question is presented you are expected to do it in the following manner. $$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}x^{2n}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2nx^{2n-1}$$ Therefore, $$\frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}=2n\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2n-1}$$